# How to open a Vimeo (or YouTube) video in a new window of max size 80% of the screen sizes?

Tags: video, iframe, size

I would like to do the following on a website :

- when clicking on a image, I would like to open a Vimeo (or YouTube) video in a new window of max size 80% of the screen sizes.
- without using iframe

Answer (score 0):

window.open(videolink, 'newwindow', "width=700,height=500,winname,directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=800,height=500")

Comment: If you want to thank somebody, you can give them an upvote.